# Why would a Blue Angels pilot leave their gear down?

Tags: landing-gear, pilot-technique, airshow

In a recent Blue Angels airshow, one of the pilots had their landing gear down during the first 5 minutes of the show. What possible reasons would justify leaving the aircraft in this state?

No picture available.

Comment: Perhaps ironically because it makes a nice picture?

Comment: Trying to flow slow to give the amateur photogs a chance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**What possible reasons would justify leaving the aircraft in this state?**

Because it's part of [their show routine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Angels):

> - Solos Take-off (Blue Angel #5: **Dirty** Roll on Take-Off; Blue Angel #6: Low Transition to High Performance Climb).

This dirty roll is not easy (it killed a Blue Angel back in 1982 in a [Skyhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_A-4_Skyhawk) during winter training), so it shows off skill and plane capability.

And later four planes fly gear down:

> - Diamond **Dirty** Loop: The diamond flies a loop with all 4 jets in the carrier landing configuration.

The dirty loop formation started back in 1986 to celebrate the 40th anniversary and the new F/A-18:

> On 8 November 1986, the Blue Angels completed their 40th anniversary year during ceremonies unveiling their present aircraft, the McDonnell Douglas F/A-18 Hornet. The power and aerodynamics of the Hornet allows them to perform a slow, high angle of attack "tail sitting" maneuver, and to fly a "**dirty**" (landing gear down) formation loop.

---

Dirty is plane-speak for gear and/or flaps out, as opposed to a *clean* configuration.

[image]
Source: [pinterest.com](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/202099102003779951/)

Comment: Hm... Flaps certainly don't help with inverted flight, but generally it's _easier_ to fly "dirty" (with lots of added drag) at low speeds, esp. in formation. Provided, of course, there is enough power for this.

Comment: If I had enough reputation, I would select this as answer.

Comment: @mario87: Thanks. You can press the check mark to accept it.